# How to set baud rate from 19200 to 115200 in android.?

Tags: android, arduino, usb, communication

I am creating an android application that consists of usb host communication. In this i used 19200 baud rate but here i want it by 115200. please tell me how to set baud rate 115200
This is my activity:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        textOut = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.textout);
        buttonSend = (Button)findViewById(R.id.send);

        buttonSend.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) 
            {
                textToSend = textOut.getText().toString();
                if(textToSend!="")
                {
                    stringToRx = "";

                    Thread threadsendArduinoText = new Thread(new Runnable()
                    {
                            @Override
                            public void run() 
                            {

                                sendArduinoText(textToSend);
                            }
                    });
                            threadsendArduinoText.start();
                }

            }});

        usbManager = (UsbManager)getSystemService(Context.USB_SERVICE);
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();

        Intent intent = getIntent();
        String action = intent.getAction();

        UsbDevice device = (UsbDevice)intent.getParcelableExtra(UsbManager.EXTRA_DEVICE);
        if (UsbManager.ACTION_USB_DEVICE_ATTACHED.equals(action)) 
        {
            setDevice(device);
        } 
        else if (UsbManager.ACTION_USB_DEVICE_DETACHED.equals(action)) 
        {
            if (deviceFound != null && deviceFound.equals(device)) 
            {
                setDevice(null);
            }
        }
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unused")
    private void setDevice(UsbDevice device) {
        usbInterfaceFound = null;
        endpointOut = null;
        endpointIn = null;

        for (int i = 0; i < device.getInterfaceCount(); i++) {          
            UsbInterface usbif = device.getInterface(i);

            UsbEndpoint tOut = null;
            UsbEndpoint tIn = null;

            int tEndpointCnt = usbif.getEndpointCount();
            if (tEndpointCnt >= 2) 
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < tEndpointCnt; j++) 
                {
                    if (usbif.getEndpoint(j).getType() == UsbConstants.USB_ENDPOINT_XFER_BULK) 
                    {
                        if (usbif.getEndpoint(j).getDirection() == UsbConstants.USB_DIR_OUT) 
                        {
                            tOut = usbif.getEndpoint(j);
                        } else if (usbif.getEndpoint(j).getDirection() == UsbConstants.USB_DIR_IN) 
                        {
                            tIn = usbif.getEndpoint(j);
                        }
                    }
                }

                if (tOut != null && tIn != null) 
                {
                    // This interface have both USB_DIR_OUT
                    // and USB_DIR_IN of USB_ENDPOINT_XFER_BULK
                    usbInterfaceFound = usbif;
                    endpointOut = tOut;
                    endpointIn = tIn;
                }
            }
        }

        if (usbInterfaceFound == null) 
        {
            return;
        }

        deviceFound = device;

        if (device != null)
        {
            UsbDeviceConnection connection = usbManager.openDevice(device);
            if (connection != null && 
                connection.claimInterface(usbInterfaceFound, true))
            {

                connection.controlTransfer(0x21, 34, 0, 0, null, 0, 0);
                connection.controlTransfer(0x21, 32, 0, 0, new byte[] { (byte) 0x80, 0x25, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x08 }, 7, 0);
                usbDeviceConnection = connection;
                Thread thread = new Thread(this);
                thread.start();

            } 
            else 
            {
                usbDeviceConnection = null;
            }
         }
    }

    private void sendArduinoCommand(int control)
    {
        synchronized (this) 
        {

            if (usbDeviceConnection != null)
            {
                byte[] message = new byte[2];
                usbDeviceConnection.bulkTransfer(endpointOut,message, message.length, 0);
                Log.d(TAG, "sendArduinoCommand: " + String.valueOf(control));
            }
        }
    }

    private void sendArduinoText(String s) 
    {
        synchronized (this) 
        {

            if (usbDeviceConnection != null) 
            {

                int length;
                out= textOut.getText().toString();
                byte[] b = new byte[1];
                b = out.getBytes();

                    usbDeviceConnection.controlTransfer(0x40, 0x03, 0x2580, 0, null, 0, 0); //baudrate 9600
                    usbDeviceConnection.bulkTransfer(endpointOut,b, b.length, 0);
                    try 
                    {
                        Thread.sleep(100);
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) 
                    {

                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void run() 
    {
        ByteBuffer buffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(1);
        UsbRequest request = new UsbRequest();
        request.initialize(usbDeviceConnection, endpointIn);
        while (true) 
        {
            request.queue(buffer, 1);
            if (usbDeviceConnection.requestWait() == request) 
            {
                byte dataRx = buffer.get(0);
            }
            } 

            }


    }
```

Comment: The only applicable baud rate is on the *far* side ofa USB serial coverter.  How you tell the converter chip over USB to change the baud rate on its far side depends on which chip you are using.  You may well be already setting it to something with one of your control transfers.